# get all textarea content in sortable order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I want get all textarea content in sortable order and insert in other textarea:

**Option 1**: $("div textarea").val();

**Option 2**: $("div textarea").text();

Problem:

**Option 1**: val update with new input, but get val only from div #1

**Option 2**: get all in sortable order, but val no update with new input

**Code**:

```js
$(function() {

$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      out: function( event, ui ) {change();}
});


function change(){ 

         var content = "";

         $("#result textarea").empty();
         $("#sortable" ).sortable('toArray', {attribute: 'value'});           

         //content = $("div textarea").text(); // get all, but no update
         //content = $("div textarea").val(); // get only val from #1

         $("#result textarea").text(content); 

}

});
```

```html
<ul id="sortable">
    <div id="1" value="1">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50">01---</textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="2" value="2">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50">02---</textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="3" value="3">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50">03---</textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="4" value="4">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50">04---</textarea>
    </div>
</ul>

    <div id="result" value="result">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can do it in plain jquery -- https://jsfiddle.net/puz93284/

Comment: a more fuller demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/7w9u1jcr/

Comment: Thanks Tasos. But this example not is the draggable and is restricted to 4 elements.

Comment: no prob, it may come handy one day ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `out` to `stop`, so the change will fire when sorting has stopped which will make the call to update the list, using `content = $("div textarea").text();` to write the text

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      change();
    }
  });

  $("#sortable textarea").on('change keyup paste', change);

  function change() {
    var content = "";

    $("#result textarea").empty();
    $("#sortable").sortable('toArray', {
      attribute: 'value'
    });

    $("div textarea").each(function() {
      content += this.value;
    });

    $("#result textarea").text(content);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="sortable">
    <div id="1" value="1">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50">01---</textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="2" value="2">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50">02---</textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="3" value="3">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50">03---</textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="4" value="4">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50">04---</textarea>
    </div>
</ul>

    <div id="result" value="result">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tested the code, but get text from div and not updated with new val input. This is the problem option2.

Comment: I have updated the code to include this, https://jsbin.com/xadapisoho/edit?html,js,console,output is this what you require? added a listener for user input

Comment: Yes. That's it. Thanks user2950720.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that .text() only once updates the textarea visibly, so .val() is the way to go. Type in a textarea and see it doesn't change the html, but it changes the val.

Maybe you are not getting the content properly, so use console.log to test that. Maybe you need to loop through each textarea, and append the val to your content var.

Comment: Yes. But how to get in order? val acess content of div name.

Comment: I see it was already solved, indeed by looping. I'd still set the result via val.

Comment: Tried the jsbin example above, which works but is flawed. Trying with .val() produces duplicated strings. Reason: "div textarea" is wrong selector... .val() also gets contents from #results but .text() could NOT read that content (hint!!!)  Proper selector: #sortable textarea ... and use .val() to populate #results

Comment: Yes. Thanks. My real code is different.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35815394/2015/plurality/index.html
The idea is make a IDE with it.

Comment: all right... be aware that content in newly added boxes is only added after dragging

Comment: Yes. It's just a draft prototype yet. Missing blocks to add modules like MIT Scratch, Google Blockly and MIT App Inventor.